# new google.maps.places.PlacesService throwing error

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writing an angularjs app which uses Google maps and places api. for google maps am using angular-google-maps.js and registering in the application module as:

```js
app.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: appConfig.placesApiKey,
        v: '3',
        libraries:'weather,geometry,visualization,places'
    });
});
```

**In the controller:**

```js
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (map) {
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: geocodeObject.latitude, longitude: geocodeObject.longitude }, zoom: 15 };

    var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
});
```

Following error is shown in the console when newing the places service object:
this.j.getElementsByTagName is not a function  at places_impl.js

Since the placesService is null, I cannot make any further calls.

Please provide any help on whats being done incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error since the constructor of `google.maps.places.PlacesService class` accepts *the instance* of `google.maps.Map class` but `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` provider returns Google Maps API types.

From another hand, `uiGmapIsReady` service is better suited for initializing `google.maps.places.PlacesService class`. The map control is not guaranteed to be initialized until the `uiGmapIsReady` service's promise resolves.

Having said that i would suggest to place the initialization of  `google.maps.places.PlacesService class` into `uiGmapIsReady` service:

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise()                    
.then(function(maps) {                 
    var mapControl = $scope.mapControl.getGMap();
    var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapControl);
});
```

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

app.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //key: appConfig.placesApiKey,
        v: '3',
        libraries:'weather,geometry,visualization,places'
    });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, uiGmapIsReady) {

     $scope.mapControl = {};

     uiGmapIsReady.promise()                    
    .then(function(maps) {                 
        var mapControl = $scope.mapControl.getGMap();
        var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapControl);
    });
   
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 37.78, longitude: -122.41 }, zoom: 15 };
    });

});
```

```css
.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
        <div class="angular-google-map-container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options" control="mapControl">
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/010umeyn/) that demonstrates how to utilize `google.maps.places.PlacesService class`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks it worked. Where do i get the documentation around the uiGmapIsReady and related angular-google maps stuff?

Comment: Besides source code a lot of useful information could be found in  angular-google-maps repository ;)

Comment: I was having trouble loading the places library until I found that you can't have whitespace between the library names. (Should've copy and pasted from @VadimGremyachev's comment.. Perhaps this comment could save others headache..


Eg Correct:
`libraries:'weather,geometry,visualization,places'`


Eg Incorrect:
`libraries:'weather, geometry, visualization, places'`


I've raised the issue https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1782